# Prove that if $a_{n} \to A$ for some real $A$ then $a_{n}^{2} \to A^{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence of reals convergent to $A$. We have
$$|a_{n}^{2} - A^{2}| = |a_{n} - A||a_{n} + A|.$$ 
I am stuck at majorizing $|a_{n} + A|.$ I know that convergent sequences are bounded, but, that kind of bounds, which takes the form $\max \{ |a_{1}|, \dots, |a_{N-1}|, \varepsilon + |A| \}$ where $N$ depends on $\varepsilon,$ does not seem to be useful here, right?

Comment: Here is one way to get a bound: $a_n\to A$ implies that there exist a $M$ s.t. $|a_n| < |A| + 1$ for all $n>M$. This means that $|a_n + A| < 2|A| + 1$ if $n>M$...

Comment: That is false, Jürgen. Take $a_n = 1/n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $a_n \to A$, there exist a positive integer $N_1$ such that $|a_n - A| < 1$ for all $n \ge N_1$. Then $|a_n + A| = |(a_n - A) + 2A| \le |a_n - A| + 2|A| < 1 + 2|A|$ for all $n \ge N_1$. Again, as $a_n \to A$, there exists a positive integer $N_2$ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon/(1 + 2|A|)$ for all $n \ge N_2$. Hence, if $n > \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ then $$|a_n^2 - A^2| = |a_n - A||a_n + A| < \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + 2|A|}(1 + 2|A|) = \varepsilon$$ Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, $a_n^2 \to A^2$.

Comment: Thanks; neat. I overlooked the relation $|a_{n} + A| = |a_{n} - A + 2A|$ :(

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, choose $N_1$ such that : $|a_n-A| < 1$ for $n > N_1$,  and choose $N_2$ such that $|a_n-A| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2|A|+1}$ for $n > N_2$. Then if $n > N = \text{max}(N_1,N_2) \Rightarrow |a_n^2-A^2| = |a_n-A||a_n+A| \leq |a_n-A|\left(|a_n-A|+2|A|\right) < (2|A|+1)|a_n-A|< \epsilon \Rightarrow a_n^2\to A^2$.